# EditText crashes when adding an inputtype

Tags: android, dialog, crash, nullpointerexception, android-edittext

In my android application I have a dialog box in which the user inputs info into an `EditText` and saves the data. Everything so far worked fine until I added an `inputType` to the `EditTexts`. I can't seem to find the solution to this problem, I'm rather new to android programming and programming in general so it might be a dumb mistake but I can't figure it out. Here some of the code:

```
private Dialog dialog() {
    Dialog diUnit = new Dialog(Overzicht.this);
    diUnit.setContentView(R.layout.unitdialog);
    EditText etKM = (EditText) diUnit.findViewById(R.id.etKM);
    etKM.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    diUnit.setTitle("Add unit");
    diUnit.setCancelable(false);
    diUnit.getWindow().getAttributes().width = LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
    bUnitDialogSave = (Button) diUnit.findViewById(R.id.bUnitDialogVoegToe);
    bUnitDialogCancel = (Button) diUnit.findViewById(R.id.bUnitDialogCancel);
    bUnitDialogCancel.setOnClickListener(this);
    bUnitDialogAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    return diUnit;
}
```

And the logcat :

[image: image 1]

I know it's not storing the `EditText` input yet but the problem starts as soon as I add the setInputType line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to inflate the layout `R.layout.unitdialog` into a `View`(with the `LayoutInflater`) and then search for that `EditText` in the inflated `View`:

```
private Dialog dialog() {
    Dialog diUnit = new Dialog(Overzicht.this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getLayoutInflater();
    View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.unitdialog, null);
    diUnit.setContentView(content);
    EditText etKM = (EditText) content.findViewById(R.id.etKM);
    etKM.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    diUnit.setTitle("Add unit");
    diUnit.setCancelable(false);
    diUnit.getWindow().getAttributes().width = LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
    bUnitDialogSave = (Button) diUnit.findViewById(R.id.bUnitDialogVoegToe);
    bUnitDialogCancel = (Button) diUnit.findViewById(R.id.bUnitDialogCancel);
    bUnitDialogCancel.setOnClickListener(this);
    bUnitDialogAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    return diUnit;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, I tried to inflate the layout but I still get a crash at startup and the same logCat.

Comment: @user1219263 `ttKM.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER)` is the line 64 in the class `Overzicht`?

Comment: Yes, that's line 64. The logCat reports the onCreate method in which the initialize method is called (which is also reported in the logCat) and within the initialize method the dialog method is called in which it report the line " etKM.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);"

Comment: @user1219263 Your `EditText` is null. Are you sure you have a `EditText` with the id `"@+id/etKM"` in your `R.layout.unitdialog`? Have you tried to go to the menu of Eclipse and then Project -> Clean?

Comment: Ah thanks! I had a test xml file not in use with these id's but in the R.layout.unitdialog they had no id given. Stupid mistake, thanks so much for your answer I literally have been searching for the problem for hours.

Comment: @user1219263 Glad i could help. Also please mark my answer as correct so the question becomes answered :)